# ECHO a <script> via php. I want to know the proper way to do it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a url path that will send through this `myGlobalFunction();` from a different file.

So the following script tag will catch the user on the website root and forward him to the login page. I can't seem to make this working. I know i am missing the single and double quotes. :(

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['role']))
{
  echo '<script>window.location.assign("'.myGlobalFunction().'/onboardingform/core/admin/login.php")</script>';
  exit();

  } else if (isset($_SESSION['role'])) {


        if($_SESSION['role'] =='CLIENT') {

              echo "<script>window.location.assign('/onboardingform/core/client/index.php')</script>";
              exit();

        } else if($_SESSION['role'] =='RESELLER') {

              echo "<script>window.location.assign('/onboardingform/core/reseller/index.php')</script>";
              exit();

        } else if($_SESSION['role'] =='CSR') {

              echo "<script>window.location.assign('/onboardingform/core/csr/index.php')</script>";
              exit();

        } else if($_SESSION['role'] == 'ADMIN') {


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not concatenating the strings properly. Use `.` operator to concatenate the string like this.

```
<?php

echo '<script>window.location.assign("'. myGlobalFunction().'/onboardingform/core/admin/login.php")</script>';
```

And there is no need of `echo` statement inside another `echo`.

Comment: Yes.. I found it and i tried to do the same thing which you wrote here.. It works.. But for a split seconf it shows the variable on the screen.. Example: /onboardingform/ and the lods the login.php...

Comment: May be You've put `echo` in the `myGlobalFunction()` function.

Comment: hmmm.. Yes.. the myGlobalFunction() has an echo... because i want it to send the /onboardingform/ when i call it.

Comment: You can use `return` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['role']))
{
  echo "<script>window.location.assign('" . myGlobalFunction() . "/onboardingform/core/admin/login.php')</script>";
  exit();
}
```